# How to not apply a style on chapter first pages?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to put a footer in all my document so I use the following code :

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           
\pagestyle{fancy}           
\lfoot[\thepage]{} 
\cfoot{\tiny{$\copyright $} 
\rfoot[]{\thepage} % droite du pied de page
\fancyhead[RO, LE] {}
```

It works well except for the first page of all my chapters which apparently have their own style. I don't know why they are different (I just take the template from internet at this address : https://github.com/DorianDepriester/TemplateThese/archive/master.zip).

Currently, I can solve the problem for all chapters using this command : `\thispagestyle{fancy}\protect` at the beginning of all my chapters but as my list of figures and table of content is longer than 1 page, it didn't work for them.

So if you have any solution to put this code at the beginning of the list of figures or just remove the default page style for all chapter first pages, I am very interested.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Check the documentation of fancyhdr, section "redefining plain style".

Comment: Thanks I had a look but I didn't found the good information. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Unrelated: beware this template loads obsolete  (`ae` and àecompl`) or incompatible packages (`lmodern` and `fourier`, `enumerate` and `enumitem`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redefine the `plain` style that's used for the chapter starting pages.

You can also streamline the definitions.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}           

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}           

\fancyhf{}% clear all fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textcopyright}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textcopyright}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [fancyhdr documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) gives a couple of suggestions. First you'd probably want to clear all header and footer fields. Using `\fancyhf{}`. Second `\lfoot` and `\rfoot` does not take optional arguments! So you end up with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\tiny{$\copyright $}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
  Hello world
  \newpage
  foo bar
\end{document}
```